# How to conditionally resize image if screen not wide enough, with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, resize, width

Say I have a 400 px wide and 250 px high image. The user resizes the screen or loads the page on a smartphone.

Say the screen width is 320 px wide. The 400 px image won't fit.

Is there a way to automatically resize the image (and keep proportions) when the screen is not wide enough, using CSS?

In other words the image should be resized from 400px wide to 320px wide (for example).

Comment: you can use media queries for this

Comment: But Media queries require fixed break points...

Comment: put width="100%" in your `<img>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Google responsive images for more information.
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/

Answer (score 2):

No need to use mediaqueries for this specific case: just define

```
#yourimage {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 400px;
}
```

this will ensure a full-width image for every viewport width up to 400px

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both min and max:

*demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Vv9RT/

*css*:

```
img {
    min-width: 220px;
    max-width: 420px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Try changing the panel size in the fiddle. `min-height` will ensure a minimum acceptable size when the screen size gets too low. `max-height` will ensure a maximum size so that it doesn't get huge.

100% width will keep it within bounds.

Answer (score 0):

by using the css3 media queries u can do make possible

```
ex: @media screen (max-width:480px){
      img{
           width:320px;
     }
}
```

or

```
 img{ max-width:100%}
```

or else you can use both..  `'img{ max-width:100%}'` place before the media quires